# Mongo document not updating with graphQL and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, graphql

Menu App prototype, very very new to graphql so I am having issues with updating a document, sending document data is fine so Ill have an ID I can use to target the document I want. Not even sure how to ask this question but updating isnt working and is returning Null. I am using the findbyidandupdate method for mongoose. updateMenu in the root value is the function with issues.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const cors = require('cors');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql')


const port = 8081;
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json())

const menuCollection = require('./models/menu')


app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema: buildSchema(`
        type Menu {
        _id: ID!
        number: String!
        title: String!
        description: String!
        priceSML: String!
        priceMED: String!
        priceLGE: String!
        vegetarian: Boolean!
        vegan: Boolean!
        veganOption: Boolean!
        gluetenFreeOption: Boolean!
        }


        input MenuInput {
        _id: ID
        number: String
        title: String
        description: String
        priceSML: String
        priceMED: String
        priceLGE: String
        vegetarian: Boolean
        vegan: Boolean
        veganOption: Boolean
        gluetenFreeOption:Boolean
        }

        type RootQuery {
            menus: [Menu!]!
        }

        type RootMutation {
            createMenu(menuInput: MenuInput): Menu
            updateMenu(menuInput: MenuInput): Menu
        }

  

        schema {
            query: RootQuery 
            mutation: RootMutation
        }
    `),
    rootValue: {
        //get all menu documents
        menus: () => {
            return menuCollection.find()
                .then(menus => {
                    return menus.map(menu => {
                        return { ...menu._doc };
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    throw err
                })
        },
        //add new document to menu collection
        createMenu: (args) => {
            const menu = new menuCollection({
                number: args.menuInput.number,
                title: args.menuInput.title,
                description: args.menuInput.description,
                priceSML: args.menuInput.priceSML,
                priceMED: args.menuInput.priceMED,
                priceLGE: args.menuInput.priceLGE,
                vegetarian: args.menuInput.vegetarian,
                vegan: args.menuInput.vegan,
                veganOption: args.menuInput.veganOption,
                gluetenFreeOption: args.menuInput.gluetenFreeOption
            })

            return menu
                .save()
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    return { ...result._doc };
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    throw err;
                });

        },
        updateMenu: (args) => {
            return menuCollection.findByIdAndUpdate(args.menuInput._id, args)

                .then(test => {
                    console.log(args.menuInput.id)
                    return test
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    throw err
                })



        }

    },
    graphiql: true
}))


//ENV variables for mongo connection auth
const mongoDbData = {
    mongoUser: process.env.DB_USER,
    mongoPassword: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    mongoCluster: process.env.DB_CLUSTER,
    mongoDatabase: process.env.DB_NAME
}

//connect to our mongoDB with mongoose and env varaibles
//server port listener
//server only starts if connection to mongoDB is successful
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${mongoDbData.mongoUser}:${mongoDbData.mongoPassword}@${mongoDbData.mongoCluster}.c0l8o.mongodb.net/${mongoDbData.mongoDatabase}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`).then(() => {
    console.log('Successful connection to database')
    app.listen(port, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log("Error in server setup")
        console.log(`Server listening on Port ${port}`);
    })
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Here is the query I am using on graphiQl

```
mutation {
    updateMenu(menuInput: {_id: "625e8c085ac1c160d9790223",title: "new title"}){
    title
  }
}
```

the id is the one from the document I am trying to update.
Big thanks, Im new enough to graphql to barely understand how to even ask the question, unfortunately ive got some time pressure or else id be burning through tutorials lmao

Comment: You should read [the fine manual](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate), specifically about `options.returnDocument` and what its default setting is. But it seems your issue is a Mongoose issue, not GraphQL (because you say that "sending document data is fine").

Comment: Yep Im able to pull data from the db using a graphql query, ill read that manual thanks